# Copying row element in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `X` of `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` format with shape `(44, 4095)`

I would like to now to create a new numpy array say `X_train = np.empty([44, 4095])` and copy row by row in a different order. Say I want the 5th row of `X` in 1st row of `X_train`.

How do I do this (copying an entire row into a new numpy array) similar to matlab?

Answer (score 6):

Define the new row order as a list of indices, then define `X_train` using [integer indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing):

```
row_order = [4, ...]
X_train = X[row_order]
```

Note that unlike Matlab, Python uses 0-based indexing, so the 5th row has index 4.

Also note that integer indexing (due to its ability to select values in *arbitrary* order) returns a *copy* of the original NumPy array.

This works equally well for sparse matrices and NumPy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Python works generally by reference, which is something you should keep in mind. What you need to do is make a copy and then swap. I have written a demo function which swaps rows.

```
import numpy as np # import numpy

''' Function which swaps rowA with rowB '''
def swapRows(myArray, rowA, rowB):
    temp = myArray[rowA,:].copy() # create a temporary variable 
    myArray[rowA,:] = myArray[rowB,:].copy() 
    myArray[rowB,:]= temp

a = np.arange(30) # generate demo data
a = a.reshape(6,5) # reshape the data into 6x5 matrix

print a # prin the matrix before the swap
swapRows(a,0,1) # swap the rows
print a # print the matrix after the swap
```

To answer your question, one solution would be to use

```
X_train = np.empty([44, 4095])
X_train[0,:] = x[4,:].copy() # store in the 1st row the 5th one
```

unutbu answer seems to be the most logical.

Kind Regards,